# c++ Dynamic cast with nested polymorphic template

Tags: c++, polymorphism, message-queue, dynamic-cast

I'm using [PolyM message queue](https://github.com/khuttun/PolyM) that offers messages

```
class Msg
```

and messages with template payload

```
template<typename PayloadType> class DataMsg: public Msg
```

This works until I nest the DataMsg template inside another DataMsg, like this...

```
DataMsg<DataMsg<int>>
```

and try to extract the nested DataMsg to pass it on for further processing. For this, I cast to the Msg base type like this:

```
function(Msg &base) {
    auto &msg = dynamic_cast<DataMsg<Msg>&>(base).getPayload();
}
```

This cast fails with a bad cast exception. Using a static_cast instead seems not to have any side effects.

From a polymorphic view point I can't see anything wrong with my approach. As dynamic casting works for the non-nested type, it should work for the nested one too?

I've asked this question on the PolyM [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/khuttun/PolyM/issues/5#issuecomment-437478240), however did not get a proper explanation why the cast fails.

This is a minimalistic example that shows the problem:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Msg {
  public:
     virtual ~Msg() {}
};

template<typename PayloadType>
class DataMsg: public Msg {
  public:
     virtual ~DataMsg() {}

     PayloadType& getPayload() const
     {
       return *pl_;
     }

  private:
    PayloadType* pl_;
};

static void getInnerMsg(Msg &msgMsg) { 
    try { 
        auto &msg = dynamic_cast<DataMsg<Msg>&>(msgMsg).getPayload();
        std::cout << "cast OK" << endl;
    } catch ( std::bad_cast& bc ) {      
        std::cerr << "bad_cast caught: " << bc.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

and my test cases:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
     Msg                     msg1;
     DataMsg<int>            msg2;
     DataMsg<Msg>            msg3;
     DataMsg<DataMsg<int>>   msg4;

    cout << "expect bad cast (no nested message)" << endl;
    getInnerMsg(msg1);
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "expect bad cast (no nested message)" << endl;
    getInnerMsg(msg2);
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "expect successful cast (nested message base type)" << endl;
    getInnerMsg(msg3);
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "expect successful cast (nested message child type)" << endl;
    getInnerMsg(msg4);

    return 0;
}
```

Run with "g++ test.cpp -o test.x && ./test.x". The GitHub issue contains a more complete usage example.

Comment: Why do you expect successful cast in case 4? `DataMsg<DataMsg<int>>` does not have any subject of `DataMsg<Msg>` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From a polymorphic view point I can't see anything wrong with my approach. As dynamic casting works for the non-nested type, it should work for the nested one too?

When it comes to templates, `A<B>` and `A<C>` are distinct unrelated types, even if `B` and `C` are related. Using a reference you obtain with `static_cast` leads to undefined behavior. To illustrate, if we were to hand-write your resulting class hierarchy, it will be akin to this

```
struct base { ~virtual base() = default; };

struct foo : base {
    base *p;
};

struct bar : base {
    foo *p;
};
```

In the above sample, if the dynamic type of the object is `bar`, it cannot be cast to a `foo&`, those types are not in an inheritance chain with each other, and a dynamic cast will fail as it should. But a `static_cast` from `base&` (referring to a `bar`) to `foo&` will succeed. There is no run-time check, and the compiler takes you at your word about the types, but you did not tell it the truth. Undefined behavior follows if you use that reference. Sadly the appearance of "working" is a valid manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: I think all three answers are correct, however this is short, accurate and points me to having undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As (briefly) explained in the github issue reply:

```
function(Msg &base) {
    auto &msg = dynamic_cast<DataMsg<Msg>&>(base).getPayload();
}
```

Here you try to cast from `Msg` to `DataMsg<Msg>`. However, you indicate that the dynamic type of `base` is `DataMsg<DataMsg<int>>`. `DataMsg<Msg>` inherits from `Msg` and `DataMsg<DataMsg<int>>` inherits from `Msg`, but they are otherwise unrelated (regardless of the relation between the template arguments).

More generally speaking, `MyClass<Derived>` does not inherit from `MyClass<Base>` - (no matter if both derive from the same base class), so dynamic casting one from/to the other is illegal (through/from common base or not).

Answer (score 0):

> This works until I nest the DataMsg template inside another DataMsg ...  try to extract the nested DataMsg

So far your logic makes intuitive sense for unpacking nested messages.

You have a generic message with a generic header containing a dynamic concrete message of some specific type, extract the specific message payload, that contains another message of another specific type, etc.

All that is perfectly fine.

Your conceptual problem is that you're treating nested template parameters like nested message objects, and they're not the same at all.

```
template<typename PayloadType> class DataMsg: public Msg
    // ...
  private:
    PayloadType* pl_;
};
```

means every instantiation of the `DataMsg` template *is-a* `Msg` and it *has-a* pointer to the contained payload.

Now, every instantiation of `DataMsg` is a new type `DataMsg<X>`, which is unrelated to any other instantiation `DataMsg<Y>` even if `X` and `Y` are related (except that they both derive from `Msg`). So:

```
DataMsg<DataMsg<int>>
```

*is-a* `Msg` and *has-a* pointer to a `DataMsg<int>` (which itself *is-a* `Msg`), while

```
DataMsg<Msg>
```

also *is-a* `Msg`, and *has-a* pointer to a `Msg`, but is still a new type unrelated to `DataMsg<DataMsg<int>>` (except by having a common base) even though the payload pointer types are convertible.

So, your ideas about message layout are fine, but you're not modelling them correctly in the type system. If you want to do this, you could explicitly specialize for nested messages:

```
using NestedMsg = DataMsg<Msg>;

template<typename NestedPayloadType>
class DataMsg<DataMsg<NestedPayloadType>>: public NestedMsg {
  public:
     NestedPayloadType const & getDerivedPayload() const
     {
       // convert nested Msg payload to derived DataMsg
       return dynamic_cast<DataMsg<NestedPayloadType> const &>(this->getPayload());
     }
};
```

Now `DataMsg<DataMsg<int>>` really *is-a* `DataMsg<Msg>`. As such it inherits `Msg const& DataMsg<Msg>::getPayload() const`, and you can still get the derived type of the payload (`DataMsg<int>`) by calling `getDerivedPayload().

Your other `getPayload` method should also return a const ref, BTW.

Comment: > If you want to do this, you could explicitly specialize for nested messages: 

This makes the minimal example to run fine, however as soon as I want to use the getDerivedPayload() function, I get an compilation error. 
It also only gives me the inserted payload, but my initial approach was to extract the entire nested message for further processing. Is this even possible?

> Your other getPayload method should also return a const ref, BTW.

getPayload() is used in PolyM for getting and setting a message, so can't be const.

Comment: **auto &pMsg4 = msg4.getDerivedPayload();** gives me the error **error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const int&’ from expression of type ‘const DataMsg<int>’
        return dynamic_cast<DataMsg<NestedPayloadType> const &>(this->getPayload());**

Comment: I've now solved this problem by using _pointer-to-msg_ as payload instead of _msg_ as reccomended by the maintainer [github](https://github.com/khuttun/PolyM/issues/5#issuecomment-444470772). I think this is a cleaner solution to the problem